# Microsoft Power Automate - error with flow - Action 'Parse_JSON' failed

Tags: power-automate

I have an error with my flow - Action 'Parse_JSON' failed:

Details:

Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'Required property 'content' expects a value but got null. Path ''.'.

[image: screenshot]

Please see the screenshot above, it appears when a the file upload feature on the MS Form is not inputted, but as this question on the Form is optional we need this flow to work either when the file upload is present or not.

Many thanks,

Andy

Comment: A little hard to help without seeing the JSON that you're trying to parse.

Comment: What did you use in the Content field of the Parse Json action? It looks like that field or property is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your JSON is expection data in a field that got null. In the example her I fixed it by adding "null" as a valid value, so "emailadress2" is no longer mandatory.
See also https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Handling-NULL-in-Parse-JSON/td-p/40906

[image]

Comment: It is giving a Content null error. I think in this case the whole object they are trying to parse is empty and not a specific property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that can work is using an expression to check for a blank string, and substituting an empty array or object:

```
if(empty(outputs('Get_response_details')?['<snip>']),'[]',outputs('Get_response_details')?['<snip>'])
```

[image]